# If $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \,dx=0$, then $f(x)=0$ for $0\leq x \leq 1$. True or False.

Tags: calculus

I need help to check if my analysis is right with exercise.

If $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \,dx=0$, then $f(x)=0$ for $0\leq x \leq 1$. True or False.

I think this is true because if $f(x)=0$ for $0\leq x \leq 1$ then we have:

$$\int_{0}^{1} 0 \,dx = 0 (1-0) = 0(1)=0$$

I know that the defined integral could be $0$ as well if the limits of integration are equal $\int_{a}^{a} f(x) \,dx=0$ or if the limits of integration are equal but with opposite signs and if the function $f(x)$ is odd $\int_{-a}^{a} f(x) \,dx=0$. But the here the hypothesis says that the limits of integration are $1$ and $0$. So for me, this statement is true following the analysis I exposed before.

Comment: Remember that parts of $f$ below the x-axis count as negative when you take the integral.  So, positive and negative areas can cancel out to give an integral of $0$.

Comment: True if f is non-negative, could easily be false otherwise

Comment: @JonathanHole Even if $f$ is non-negative, it is still false.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous and non-negative then it is true.

Comment: Your analysis is not right. You were given "if A, then B", and you showed the converse, "if B, then A", is true. But in general this says nothing about the original statement (which in this case, is false).

Comment: @DavidMitra Yes I noticed now that my mistake was to assume that $f(x)=0$ when that is the conclusion of the statement, not the hypothesis. I get it now.! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it is false: $\int_0^1x-\frac12\,\mathrm dx=0$. The fact that $\int_0^10\,\mathrm dx=0$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Ok. Great. My mistake was assuming that $f(x)=0$ and that's wasn't the hypothesis, it was the conclusion. So since there are other functions that the integral in the interval $[0,1]$ is $0$ then the conclusion is false. Thank you for the counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)$ is continuous, there exists an $x$ in the interval such that $f(x) = 0$ by the mean value theorem.

But, as stated the proposition is not true.

Answer (score 0):

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, if $f$ is continuous and defined on $[0,1]$, then defining $F$ by,

$$F(x)=\int_0^xf(s)ds$$

we have that $F'(x)=f(x)$, for all $x$ in $(0,1)$. As a consequence,

$$\int_0^1f(s)ds=F(1)-F(0)$$.

If we take $F(1)=F(0)$ we will have $\int_0^1f(s)ds=0$. For instance, take $F(x)=x(x-1)$, then $F(0)=F(1)=0$ and $f(x)=F'(x)=2x-1$. In this case, $f$ is not null on $[0,1]$.